# lodash: only importing chain does not work nice

Tags: javascript, lodash

The following code works:

```
let _ = require('lodash');
let arr= _([1,2,3,4]);
let b = arr.map((e)=>e^2);
```

The following does not work:

```
let chain = require('lodash/chain');
let arr= chain([1,2,3,4]);
let b = arr.map((e)=>e^2);
```

It gives me the following error:

> arr.map is not defined.

Is there a way to use chain without importing the whole global object?

Comment: Well, `chain` just creates a wrapper. In order to use collections functions, the `collections` package must be included.

Comment: Just found this article about this topic: https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.xjqw189vy . An interesting read, haven't had time to compile an answer to your question based on the article, but the article might help you in the meantime...

Comment: Interestingly the chaining example from the article using `mixin` does not seem to work for me. The `value` function does not return the resulting array... Example here: https://tonicdev.com/56c61ad30fd7d90c005ab98b/56c61ad30fd7d90c005ab98c

Answer (score 4):

You [need](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/build-differences) at least [`core`](https://lodash.com/#installation):

```
var _ = require('lodash/core');
let arr= _([1,2,3,4]);
let b = arr.map((e)=>e^2);
```

You can also roll your own [custom lodash package](https://lodash.com/custom-builds).